# Rails not booting in debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did:

```
gem install ruby-debug
```

Then it installs...

I launched using:

rails server -u -p 3002

(I also tried with -d)

I get this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3002
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
Exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add ruby-debug in your Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-debug'
```